# Inflate exception when setting text color selector to a CheckedTextView item from a custom ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, checkedtextview, inflate-exception

I have a custom ListView, which should have color selector to its background and text items.

Custom item of my list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_image"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector_blue"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm able to change the CheckedTextView background, through a selector, but when I put the selector in the text color like this `android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"`, the app crashes with the following error:

```
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612): Process: a.com.a, PID: 17612
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckedTextView
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at adapters.UsersListAdapter.getView(UsersListAdapter.java:44)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2713)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1237)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:704)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:382)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17354)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2176)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1315)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1512)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1199)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6387)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
09-02 11:36:25.918: E/AndroidRuntime(17612):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreog
```

I've googled a lot, and find many people with issue like this, but any tip can solve my issue.

These are my selectors:

text_color_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>    
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray_text" />
</selector>
```

list_item_selector_blue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/list_item_selected_blue"/>
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@color/list_item_selected_blue"/>    
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Comment: You should use `color` resources instead of drawables http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

The textColor attribute can only have a color value. So you are not allowed to define android:drawable in the selector XML (text_color_selector.xml). Just change the drawable to color, this should solve the problem. At least it did solve my problem with this change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <item 
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:color="@android:color/white"/>    
  <item
    android:color="@color/gray_text" />
</selector>
```

I assume the text color can only contain a color, and drawable allows you to define much more.